# How to use COM in C#

Tags: c#

How to reference VB 6.0 component(.dll) with C# in Visual Studio .NET 2005

After I referenced this DLL file, I can see the new icon in the reference folder icon in solution explorer. But this new icon has "!" sybbol. I double clicked this new icon that said "This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the projects is available and built."

Answer (score 5):

Just add the reference and Visual Studio will create a wrapper (Interop) assembly for you.

If you want more control over the creation of this assembly (like the name, the signing), do this at the command line using tlbimp.exe

example:

```
tlbimp.exe MyCOMDLL.dll /keyfile:KeyFile.snk /out:MyCOMInterop.dll
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I try to do this way but can't make transition successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding it as a reference to your project.  Visual studio will add a wrapper to it and you should be able to use the code?

It depends what the component is though?

Answer (score 0):

After I referenced this DLL file, I can see the new icon in the reference folder icon in solution explorer. But this new icon has "!" sybbol. I double clicked this new icon that said "This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the projects is available and built."